# Entity Framework Code First check Database exist

Tags: entity-framework-5

In Entity Framework Code first i want to check database is exist before create Database.
In code first when i call `Entities dc = new Entities()` then it goes to OnModelCreating and generate Database. How can i check if the Database exists in Entity framework Code first?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13198899/87956

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a command to check to see if a database exists from Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198869/is-there-a-command-to-check-to-see-if-a-database-exists-from-entity-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
using(var dbContext = new MyContext())
{
    if (!dbContext.Database.Exists())
        dbContext.Database.Create();
}
```

Edit:

Following the colegue sugestion, the meaning of this code is very simple: Supose your context constructor is not set to create the database, so before sending any database operations, you can check if it exists, if not, you can create a new one with the connection string parameters being the rules for the creation.

Comment: Even if your comment might be correct, adding a little explaination of what does your solution do and why it works in tue OP's context, won't harm and will encourage other users to upvote your answer.

Comment: I could not care less about upvoting, but you are right, a little explanation could help the others = ].

Answer (score 0):

This would be a static alternative, that works even without creating the DbContext first:

```csh
    System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists(dbNameOrconnectionString);
```