# Entity Framework Core - How to check if database exists?

Tags: entity-framework-core

For EF6, I can check whether a database exists in the following way:

```
context.Database.Exists()
```

How can I do this in EF Core?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I have found the solution on my own:

```
(context.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Exists()
```

It works for EF 7.0.0-rc1-final version for SqlServer

**UPDATE:**

Entity Framework Core 2.0:

```
(context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Exists()
```

Comment: Entity Framework Core 2.0: `(context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Exists()`

Comment: For EF Core 2.0: There is no need for casting, just use context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>() instead

Comment: I had wierd problem with EF Core 3.1. I needed to add manually `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;` in my code. Intellisense didnt tells me what i need to do to get `GetService()` method.

Comment: It don't correct working in EF 3.1 for me. For example database exists but Exists() method return false

Comment: @Don Tomatto Not working for us. We're using 3.1.8.

Comment: Note that this will also report false if the database is simply offline or inaccessible to the user due to permissions.  In other words, this is really not "exists", but instead more like "can I connect to it right now".

Answer (score 45):

**UPDATE** .Net Core 3.1

To check if a database exists and can be contacted:

```
dbContext.Database.CanConnect()
```

Comment: This throw `SqlException` error if the database does not exist.

Comment: @RachaneeSaengkrajai It would throw an exception if it cannot connect with the SQL server. If the database does not exists but the server is accessible, it just returns false.

Comment: For me it returns false in both cases. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Frankly I like this answer better than the accepted one simply because it's clear what you're asking.  The Exists() method is really no better than this.

Comment: This works on EF Core 7 with SQL Server

Comment: Works with EF Core 7 and Sqlite

Comment: Be careful. `CanConnect`returns `true` as soon as a connection can/could be made, even if the actual DB does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions tell you whether the database is **connectable**:

```cs
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists();  //true
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists();  //true
```

I want to know whether the database **exists**:

```cs
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().HasTables();  //true
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().HasTables();  //false
```

Note this weird behavior:

```cs
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().HasTables();  //false
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().HasTables();  //true
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().HasTables();  //true !!
```

So it's not perfect, but depending on your use case it could be useful.

Comment: `Exists()` does return `false` for me after `EnsureDeleted()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core 6.0.7:

```
dbContext.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>().CanConnect();
```

works for NpgsqlDatabaseConnector - the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.5 provider and probably for all `RelationalDatabaseCreator` descendants since it tests if database really exists as the default/base implmentation.

Comment: for Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.0 I defined the method in my class `AlternativeContext : DbContext` with the if statement `Database.CanConnect()`.